# Stream array of remote files to amazon S3 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an array of URLs to files that I want to upload to an Amazon S3 bucket. There are 2916 URLs in the array and the files have a combined size of 361MB.

I try to accomplish this using streams to avoid using too much memory. My solution works in the sense that all 2916 files get uploaded, but (at least some of) the uploads seem to be incomplete, as the total size of the uploaded files varies between 200MB and 361MB for each run.

```
// Relevant code below (part of a larger function)

/* Used dependencies and setup:
const request = require('request');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const stream = require('stream');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('config.json');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
*/

function uploadStream(path, resolve) {
    const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
    const params = { Bucket: 'xxx', Key: path, Body: pass };
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => resolve());
    return pass;
}

function saveAssets(basePath, assets) {
    const promises = [];
    assets.map(a => {
      const url = a.$.url;
      const key = a.$.path.substr(1);
      const localPromise = new Promise(
        (res, rej) => request.get(url).pipe(uploadStream(key, res))
      );
      promises.push(localPromise);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

saveAssets(basePath, assets).then(() => console.log("Done!"));
```

It's a bit messy with the promises, but I need to be able to tell when all files have been uploaded, and this part seems to work well at least (it writes "Done!" after ~25 secs when all promises are resolved).

I am new to streams so feel free to bash me if I approach this the wrong way ;-) Really hope I can get some pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was trying to complete too many requests at once. Using async.eachLimit I now limit my code to a maximum of 50 concurrent requests which is the sweetspot for me in terms of trade-off between execution time, memory consumption and stability (all of the downloads completes every time!).